# Which encryption technique should be used for users name and passwords in my notebook

Tags: encryption, passwords

i writing all my passwords and users names on my notebook

emails,amazons,facebook.

and i have really Nosy little's brothers  that will probably look at my notebook when i am not around, which encryption methods i can use that will be easy to use.

[example]
 lets say

user - iceman.

password - 245598504.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for something you can do by hand, you can use a Vigenère cipher and memorize a fairly short key.  This won't stop anyone who understands cryptography, but it should stop nosy family members.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher

You don't even have to do the enciphering by hand: http://sharkysoft.com/vigenere/  (Do inspect the code yourself to verify that the material being enciphered is processed on your computer and not sent to a server.  I believe that to be true for the link given, but always look for yourself!  Or, just do it by hand.)

Edited to add: Nosy brothers can probably crack simpler ciphers, such as the Caesar cipher.